# Refresh tokens Identity Server4

Tags: identityserver4

We are using Identity Server4 to protect our APIs. We want to use Refresh tokens to allow gaining long lived access to APIs.As per the documents("http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html") we have set the AllowOfflineAccess to true but still its not working. After AccessTokenLifeTime expire(3600 seconds), token not working. Here is the client:

```
 return new List<Client>
         {
         new Client
        {
        ClientId = "client",

        // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

        // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

        // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
            AccessTokenLifetime=3600,
            AllowOfflineAccess=true
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client app has to request the refresh token.

Please note that [refresh tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#refresh-tokens) are not available for every flow:

> Refresh tokens are supported in hybrid, authorization code and
>   resource owner password flows. To request a refresh token, the client
>   needs to include the offline_access scope in the token request (and
>   must be authorized to request for that scope).

Add this line to your client code:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Open Id connect", options =>
{
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
}
```

The way refresh tokens work:

- Login to get an *access token*. The *refresh token* is included when you use the 'offline_access' scope.
- Use the *access token* untill it expires.
- Get a new *access token* by sending the *refresh token* to the endpoint
- Depending on your strategy you can also 'refresh' the *refresh token* itself (replace the persisted refresh token with a new token). Or do not return a *refresh token* untill the token expires, having the user to login again.

Comment: thanks Ruard, Can i use hybrid, instead of client credentials?

Comment: Actually we want to protect our APIs with use of refresh token.

Comment: Yes you can use hybrid. Here's a good example: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html

Comment: Just to make sure: the refresh token has nothing to do with securing the resource. The only way to use it is to send the refresh token to the Ids4 endpoint in order to authenticate the request to obtain a new access token. It is the access token (that is included in the requests to the API) that provides access to the resource.

Comment: Just one more thing just want your feedback, I am thinking to use AWS Lambda with .NET Core. Means we don't want to expose IS4 publicly, we will create endpoint in AWS Lambda, this endpoint will interact with IS4? Is this make sence?

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS Lambda, so I cannot answer this.